# What do we mean when we say that control of the operating system is passed on to the main() function while execution of a program?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, program-entry-point

Let's assume that we are trying to run an arbitrary program -

```
int main()
{
statement 1;
statement 2;
statement 3;
}
```

Then it's often said that while execution of the program , the control of the OS is passed on to the main() function and after execution of all the statements inside the main function, the control is again passed back to OS.

What do we mean by control ? and if control is really passed from the OS to the program then how come multiple programs run at the same time ??

Comment: This second question is a subject for several chapters in a book about OS design. too broad for SO.

Comment: Where is such thing said? Context is important.

Comment: "It's often said ... ", "We all know that ..." etc. most times introduce a false assumption. And that is not "often said", but an observation of mine.

Comment: Was going to post a wiki link, but the first line of [Entry Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point) is *"In computer programming, an entry point is where control is transferred from the operating system to a computer program*"

Comment: @user2079303 Well I came across this statement at - http://www.dummies.com/programming/c/the-importance-of-the-main-function-in-c-programming/ .I hope this serves as a context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is largely the function of the linker. The linker has to identify the starting address to be executed in the program.

Some programming languages have explicit PROGRAM identifiers (e.g. Pascal, FORTRAN) to identify the starting point of the program. C uses the function name "main" to identify y the starting point.

In some implementations the C library provides a starting point that is a wrapper around main.

The procedure here is system-specific so I am going to be general. I assume that the process has been created. Now you are executing a system service to "run" your program. That system service invokes the the system program. The loader reads the instructions in the executable file to set up the process address space.

Now your program is ready to run. The "run" system service branches (usually a call) to the starting address specified in the executable file. For your C program that will be either main or a wrapper around main.

Thus your "run" system service had called your program/main/or a wrapper just like it is a function.

When your "main" finished it returns to the caller just like any other function: the "run" system service. On some systems  the system service causes the process to terminate when it resumes after a call to start function. In other systems, the system service exits and the command interpreter resumes.

> What do we mean by control ?

Control just means invoking the instruction stream your application. Your program is being called as a function from the "run" system service.

Calling a function means giving the function "control."

"Run" system service calls
    Main that calls
     any other functions that return to 
    Main when finished that returns to the 
"Run" system service.

> if control is really passed from the OS to the program then how come multiple programs run at the same time ??

For that we are getting beyond the scope of the original question. This is where terminology causes a problem. Each program runs in the a separate PROCESS. The operating system manages processes. The transfer of control here is really the transfer of control of the process; not control of the system.

Answer (score 5):

"Control" is a short way of saying "an ability to execute statements".

Before your program runs, OS executes statements to load the code of your program into memory, while your program has no ability to execute statements (i.e. has no control).

Once your program is loaded and ready to run, OS gives the code of your program an ability to execute statements, starting with `main()` function. At this point OS code that started your program waits for it to complete, i.e. no longer has control.

Comment: when you say that program loads in memory then do you refer to loading of program in ROM ??

Comment: @AashishLoknathPanigrahi The type of memory into which the program is loaded depends on the hardware. Typically, a program is loaded from disk into RAM, which may or may not be write-protected at the time the `main()` starts executing.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for being a novice to CS , so can you explain what does write-protected mean ? and how does that effect execution of program ??

Comment: @AashishLoknathPanigrahi Write-protected means your program cannot write to it. The only effect on execution of your program is if it tries writing to write-protected region, it's execution is going to end with a crash.

Comment: Can you also explain "what you meant by "The type of memory into which the program is loaded depends on the hardware"

Comment: @AashishLoknathPanigrahi I mean ROM or RAM.

Comment: So what factor affects whether program will get loaded into ROM or RAM ?

Comment: @AashishLoknathPanigrahi This depends 100% on the hardware.